# Error in my JQuery validation

Tags: php, jquery

Hello i have error in my Jquery validation, the code dont do nothing, can anybody help me?

```
<script>

    // When the user submits the form,
    //   Check what answer they picked
    //   And tell them if they're correct

    // submit
    $("#form").on("submit", function(event) {
        event.preventDefault();
        var $answer = $("#unit_name"); 
        var answer = $answer.val();
        console.log(answer);
        if (answer === "") {
            $("#result").text("Preencha corretamente o nome da unidade.");
        } else if(answer.length < 3 ) {
            $("#result").text("O nome da unidade é demasiado pequeno.");
        }

    });
    </script>
```

This is the code of the form implemented

```
                     <div class="pure-u-1">
                        <h3 align="center">Insert</h3>
                        </div>




                     <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="unit_name"Name concept:</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Insert name" id="unit_name" name="unit_name" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
                        <input type="hidden" name="state" value="insert">
                        <input type="submit" value="Insert">
                        <br><br>
                    </div>

            </form>
```

This div will show message to the users.

Comment: you are missing the closing > on the open label tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First think I noticed is that the label tag doesn't have a closing ">". It isn't in the HTML code, but does the form tag have an id of "form"?

The two lines var $answer... and var answer... could be combined to

```
var answer = $('#unit_name').val();
```

Lastly, in your html code, do you have a div (or other tag) with an id="result"? If so, is it hidden? If it is hidden, after setting your message, you will need to un-hide it.

Comment: Can you help me please

Comment: Help with what exactly?

Comment: If you need more help than offered in my answer, you will need to answer the questions I asked....